# What is SQL server connection string to connect other computer'SQL server on the network?

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I have a c# program that connects to SQL server 2008 and works with this connection string :

```
"server = HAMED-PC;database = museum ; integrated security = true";
```

I want to copy this program to another and connect to this SQL server on the network. so what should be the connection string ?

The PC that SQL server is on it have this IP `192.168.1.11`.
 I have tried so much but no success .

For example I have tried

```
 "server = 192.168.1.11;database = museum ; integrated security = true";
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: As far as I know you can't because SQL Express only accepts connections from the same computer it's running on. You're going to have to install it on the other computer aswell, copy the database over, then the connection string would work as-is (just change the PC name from 'HAMED-PC' to whatever the other computer is called)

Comment: Alex, I didn't see any restrictions on SQL Express that doesn't allow you to have connections from other PC.

Comment: @Alex that is definitely incorrect. SQL Express can *absolutely* be connected to from across a network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server express is installed by default with network access off.  You can turn it on however.

Here's how for [2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165647%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and [2008](http://kristofmattei.be/2009/10/25/sql-server-2008-express-edition-access-over-network/).

If HAMED-PC has a firewall, you will need to allow tcp port 1433.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should change the "HAMED-PC" to IP address or DNS name which is visible from other PCs.
2. If you PCs are not in Domain - you should turn on the simple SQL Server Authentication ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670(v=sql.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)). Create a new SQL Server user, add right read-write for database which you want to use on external PCs (museum I guess). And change the in connection string "integrated security = true" to "User Id=username; Password=password;"
3. Turn on the HTTP access and check that Windows Firewall doesn't block the port which is set for remote HTTP connection (there are links in other answers how to do this).